# VBScript Connection oracle in sysdba

Tags: oracle, vbscript, connect, sysdba

I need to connect in sysdba on Oracle from Vbs.

I use this command to connect on my database

```
set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")      
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")       
    ConnectionString ="Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle; Data Source=" & _
    "(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST="&computername&")(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID="&SERVICE &")(SERVER=DEDICATED)));" & _
    "User Id=system;Password="&PASSWORD &";"
cn.Open connectionString
```

but I need to connect witch / as sysdba

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
ConnectionString ="Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle; Data Source=" & _
    "(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST="&computername&")(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID="&SERVICE &")(SERVER=DEDICATED)));" & _
    "DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;User Id=system;Password="&PASSWORD &";"
```

btw, when you connect with `SYSDBA` privileges then it is usually user `SYS` not `SYSTEM` - unless you granted privilege like `GRANT SYSDBA TO SYSTEM;`

Comment: it doesn't work, I use user sys when I connect with SYSDBA

the error when I try to connect on my database is the number 3704

Answer (score 0):

it's work! with this method

`Set cmd = sh.Exec("cmd /c "& ORACLE_HOME & "\BIN\sqlplus.exe -s /@"&SERVICE &" as sysdba @Z:\Partage\Sonde\essai\test_recordset\requetesql.sql")`

```
@Z:\Partage\Sonde\essai\test_recordset\requetesql.sql
```

it's a file where we go to execute queries